# I Need Rigging help!

Tags: animation, rigging

I have one rig that's attached to my model(unselected) and one that I imported with an animation(selected). Is there a way to move the animation to my rig or merge them? I'm really new at this.

[image: 2 rigs]

Comment: if your armature have bones that have the same names as the animated armature, they will be animated

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)